# EPPlus - custom function in C# - handling cell dependencies outside of the spreadsheet

Tags: epplus

What i'm doing: added a custom function to the EPPlus runtime. This function takes a text expression as an argument (of course the text expression can be specified as an argument or can be put in some cell of the spreadsheet that we refer)
So far, so good

then we evaluate this expression outside of Excel/EPPlus - the expressions can access data outside the spreadsheet BUT ALSO can refer to other spreadsheet cells.

And there is problem with referring back to the spreadsheet - EPPlus has no idea what's in these expressions and what will be the result of their evaluation, also doesnt know if they refer to other cells that may or may not be already calculated. So - no dependency control and possible mess.

Question: can this be fixed? I mean, when the expression evaluating function detects that the expression refers to a spreadsheet cell, can it tell EPPlus to evaluate that cell first? Or at least parse the expression and detect what are the dependencies, then give this information somehow to EPPlus so it knows in what order to run the calculations?

`=MYEVAL("doSomeStuff('arg 1', Sheet.E4, Sheet.C4)")`

MYEVAL is going to be run during Worksheet.Calculate() call - but inside MYEVAL, how to tell EPPlus that we want the current value of E4 and C4 cells, if these cells are calculated themselves and can change their value during calculation?

I dont care about cyclic references, can make sure there are no cycles, just the straightforward case of running the calculations in correct order.

**Update:** just wondering, if we can add any number of arguments to the call, could we just put our dependencies in the arguments list, like this:

`=MYEVAL("doSomeStuff('arg 1', Sheet.E4, Sheet.C4)";E4;C4)`

Then EPPlus would know that before calling MYEVAL it has to calculate E4 and C4 cells. Is this enough for enforcing such dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution presented in the Update is OK/useful and appears to work.
But there is also a very simple approach, alternative: you can calculate individual cells using the EPPlus api (Worksheet.Cells[i, j].Calculate()) - then you dont need to manage the dependencies, just call Calculate on the cells you need and this will follow actual dependencies.